# Gauge invariance, symmetries, and regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, gauge-invariance, regularization, unitarity

When regularizing integrals in a QFT with a gauge symmetry, many people state that it is important that the regulator also enjoys gauge invariance.

1. Why is this true? What goes wrong when you use a regulator that breaks gauge invariance?
2. In a similar vein, does something go wrong when you use a regulator that breaks some other symmetry of the action, say translational invariance via a hard momentum cutoff?

Answer (score 2):

It is important because typically the symmetry appears to be broken if one uses the regularization which breaks this symmetry. In case of gauge symmetry it is fatal, because gauge symmetry is necessary for decoupling of unphysical (longitudinal, in case of Yang-Mills theory) modes, and thus unitarity of the theory.

Comment: But that just makes it sound like a practical necessity vs an actual necessity. Have to foolishly and wastefully work harder to see appearances deceived you.

Comment: @AHusain What is the difference between practical and actual necessity?

Comment: Just whether the formalism demands something or just wanting something tractable to be solvable in  your lifetime. For example, the formalism doesn't say not to write down some perverse gauge fixing, but if you do anything other than a Feynman or Coulomb... prescription, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, what you mean is that if the regulator breaks a symmetry, it is possible (though not guaranteed) that for some physical observable the symmetry would also be broken, which would be nonsensical. Then, is it true that if my regulator obeys all the symmetries of the action, it is guaranteed that all physical observables must also enjoy the same symmetries?

Comment: @Aaron That's right.

Comment: Is there a theorem that guarantees this to be the case, and do you have a reference?